# Conditional replace of numbers in pandas df

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

Given the following pandas df:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'1676' : ['R','NR','R','NR'],
               '1677' : ["NR", "NR" ,"NR", "NR"],
               '1710' : ["R", "R" , "NR", "NR"],
               '1536' : ["NR", "R", "NR", "R"]})

df
    1676    1677    1710    1536
0   R       NR      R       NR
1   NR      NR      R       R
2   R       NR      NR      NR
3   NR      NR      NR      R
```

and this longer pandas df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'1' : ['1710','1676','2651','1676'],
               '2' : ["2654", "2824" ,"1676", "1677"],
               '3' : ["1676", "3079" , "1677", "2085"],
               '4' : ["1536", "1677", "1409", "1536"],
                  '5' : ["510", "1710" , "1664", "1710"],
                  '6' : ["2590", "3090" , "2252", "2916"],
                  '7' : ["2777", "1536" , "1710", "3140"],
                  '8' : ["1677", "1709" , "1536", "1963"]})

    1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
0   1710    2654    1676    1536    510     2590    2777    1677
1   1676    2824    3079    1677    1710    3090    1536    1709
2   2651    1676    1677    1409    1664    2252    1710    1536
3   1676    1677    2085    1536    1710    2916    3140    1963
```

I am wondering if the following is possible row-wise (here for first row):

- for each value in `df.loc[0,] = "R"`
- take corresponding column name (number)
- search for number in `df2.loc[0,]`
- substitute number in `df2.loc[0,]` with `"R"`

So that I get this:

```
    1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
0   R       2654    R       1536    510     2590    2777    1677
1   1676    2824    3079    1677    R       3090    R       1709
2   2651    R       1677    1409    1664    2252    1710    1536
3   1676    1677    2085    R       1710    2916    3140    1963
```

**edit**:

It's not working for my specific df's. Any guesses what triggers this issue? I already tried resetting the indices.

This is df from the post above:

[image]

This is df2 from the post above:

[image]

Comment: Why are some values substituted andsome are not? Do they have to be in the same row as in the first dataframe?

Comment: yes, the rows are very important in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.where` and `replace`:

```
import numpy as np
r, c = np.where(df=='R')

df2.apply(lambda x: x.replace(df.columns[c[(r == x.name)]], 'R'), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0     R  2654     R  1536   510  2590  2777  1677
1  1676  2824  3079  1677     R  3090     R  1709
2  2651     R  1677  1409  1664  2252  1710  1536
3  1676  1677  2085     R  1710  2916  3140  1963
```

Details:

- First, find out the row and columns in df where equal to 'R'
- Use apply with axis=1 to go row by row, x.name identify which row
  index look up the position in C where that equals row index and get
  the column header from df in that position.
- Use replace to replace all values of the column header in df, on that
  row.

Comment: @Scott Boston: Thanks a lot! This is working fine!
Sadly, it's not working for my specific code which I didn't post here for reproducing purposes. I updated the post with two pictures of my df's.

Comment: Are you re assign the results to df?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go `update` with `stack` and `lookup`

```
s=df2.stack()
s=s[s.isin(df.columns)]
df2.update(pd.Series(df.mask(df=='NR').lookup(s.index.get_level_values(0),s),s.index).unstack())
df2
Out[103]: 
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0     R  2654     R  1536   510  2590  2777  1677
1  1676  2824  3079  1677     R  3090     R  1709
2  2651     R  1677  1409  1664  2252  1710  1536
3  1676  1677  2085     R  1710  2916  3140  1963
```

Comment: I don't know why I have such a mental lockup on 'lookup' I never remember that method when problem solving. +1

Comment: Never use `.lookup` either since the documentation about it is close to none. Would be useful to know in which situations to use. @Wen-Ben, maybe a q&a about it ?

Comment: @ScottBoston aha :-) ,I think lookup is not that important, I believe you know tens of way can do the same thing :-)

Comment: @Erfan just like index and columns check :-)

Comment: @Wen-Ben: Thanks a lot! This is working fine!
Sadly, it's not working for my specific code which I didn't post here for reproducing purposes. I updated the post with two pictures of my specific df's.

Comment: @Peet I can not help with the pic ...and I think if your real problem is same as what you show here, both the solution should be work